# Adding a key for "read time" to datalayer for tracking in Google Tag Manager/Analytics

Tags: google-tag-manager, data-layers

With a WP plugin, I'll be adding "read time" to each article. NOTE: Read time simply shows how long it takes to read the article, not how long a user has read my article.

I want to pull this value into Google Analytics as a custom dimension. I'd like to compare how long people are on the page (avg. time on pg.) against how long it should take to read the whole article (read time).

I understand I need to add a key for "read time" to the data layer, and pull that key into GTM. However, the documentation does not make it clear what key to add to data layer for a value like read time. Or how to create a key for it that Google Analytics will understand if that is possible.

Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The key can be anything you like. Assuming this info should be available when the article loads, you can push information to the dataLayer from the page code, or from a custom HTML tag in GTM using a window loaded page view trigger.

```
<script>
// Example of getting the read time value from a 
// DOM element with a class "read-time"
var readTime = document.querySelector('.read-time').innerText;

dataLayer.push({
  // Give an event name so that we know exactly when
  // the data becomes available in the dataLayer.
  event: "Article Viewed",
  // Add the data
  article: {
    readTime: readTime,
    title: "How to write a blog post",
    // other useful article-related properties
  }
});
</script>
```

When you have your dataLayer push working successfully, you can add a dataLayer variable in GTM to make read time available to other tags. The dataLayer key in my code example is `article.readTime`.

To send this value to GA as a custom dimension:

1. Add a custom dimension to GA. Set the scope to "hit" and make note of the index for later.
2. In GTM, add a Universal Analytics tag and set "Track Type" to Event. "Event category" could be "article," "event action" could be "article viewed" and "event label" could be the GTM built-in variable for Page URL or Page Path.
3. This is important: set "non-interaction hit" to "True."
4. "Google Analytics Settings" should be your GA settings variable. Check the "Enable overriding settings in this tag" box. Expand "More Settings" and "Custom Dimensions."
5. Click "Add Custom Dimension" and input the index of the custom dimension that you defined in GA for this purpose. Then, in the value field, put your dataLayer variable for read time.
6. Add a trigger of type "Event." In the "Event Name" field, put the event name of your dataLayer push ("Article Viewed" in my example). Save the trigger and make sure it's added to the tag.
7. Save the tag and test it in preview mode.